# How to allow caps in this input box program for pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, user-input

I found this input box module on the internet but it only allows lower case no upper. So could someone tell me what to change in the module to allow caps as im creating a small multiplayer game and i need login system and chatbox.

Here is the code example I am working with

```
# by Timothy Downs, inputbox written for my map editor

# This program needs a little cleaning up
# It ignores the shift key
# And, for reasons of my own, this program converts "-" to "_"

# A program to get user input, allowing backspace etc
# shown in a box in the middle of the screen
# Called by:
# import inputbox
# answer = inputbox.ask(screen, "Your name")
#
# Only near the center of the screen is blitted to

import pygame, pygame.font, pygame.event, pygame.draw, string
from pygame.locals import *

def get_key():
  while 1:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
      return event.key
    else:
      pass

def display_box(screen, message):
  "Print a message in a box in the middle of the screen"
  fontobject = pygame.font.Font(None,18)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10,
                    200,20), 0)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 102,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 12,
                    204,24), 1)
  if len(message) != 0:
    screen.blit(fontobject.render(message, 1, (255,255,255)),
                ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100, (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10))
  pygame.display.flip()

def ask(screen, question):
  "ask(screen, question) -> answer"
  pygame.font.init()
  current_string = []
  display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  while 1:
    inkey = get_key()
    if inkey == K_BACKSPACE:
      current_string = current_string[0:-1]
    elif inkey == K_RETURN:
      break
    elif inkey == K_MINUS:
      current_string.append("_")
    elif inkey <= 127:
      current_string.append(chr(inkey))
    display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  return string.join(current_string,"")

def main():
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320,240))
  print ask(screen, "Name") + " was entered"

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Thx!

Comment: While Padraic Cunningham appears to be correct, you could also always use tkinter or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the corresponding code to:

```
elif inkey <= 127:
    if pygame.key.get_mods() & KMOD_SHIFT or  pygame.key.get_mods() & KMOD_CAPS: # if shift is pressed  or caps is on
        current_string.append(chr(inkey).upper()) # make string uppercase
    else:
        current_string.append(chr(inkey)) # else input is lower
```

That should work.

If you want more info on keyboard modifier states look [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)

Comment: @JudiSean, No worries.